# Printing the tags beside question number with exsheets package

Tags: printing, exsheets, tags

I would like to display the tags used for each question on the right side of each question number, in a modified form, such that:
**S-20-A2, 10-Complex** would become
**[Simulation 2020 - Variant 2, Grade 10 - Complex Numbers]**
Thank you!

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{exsheets}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[a4paper,left=2cm,right=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\SetupExSheets{%
    use-tags = {20-A2}
}

\begin{document}
    \begin{question}[tags={S-20-A2, 10-Complex}]{5} 
        Content question 1
    \end{question}
    \begin{solution}
        Solution 
    \end{solution}

    \begin{question}[tags={20-A1, 10-Trig}]{5} 
         Content question 2
    \end{question}
    \begin{solution}
        Solution question 2
    \end{solution}


    \begin{question}[tags={20-A2, 10-Trig}]{5} 
        Content question 3
    \end{question}
    \begin{solution}
        Solution question 3
    \end{solution}

%[Simulation 2020 - Variant 2, Grade 10 - Complex Numbers]

\newpage
\printsolutions
\end{document}
```